# With nginx, can I redirect the user back to a URL on their local machine?

Tags: redirect, nginx

For a particular internal purpose I would like to send people back to a url on their own machine, how exactly would I do this?  I can't really do

```
server {
    server_name www.yayaya.com;
    rewrite ^(.*) localhost:3000$1 permanent;
}
```

because that will point to the server's localhost, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

either it does the lookup on the server and converts "localhost" to "127.0.0.1"
or it hands "localhost" to the client, which will still convert it to "127.0.0.1"

So either way, the client should be redirected to 127.0.0.1, which should be
correct.

I'm not an expert on nginx but I don't see why your example wouldn't work.